# Send contact us emails to multiple recipients

Tags: admin, configuration, contact-us

Is there an easy way to send the contact us to multiple recipients?  javascript validation appears to limit to one email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the easiest  solution would be to set up a proxy email address which will forward emails to the list of users.

It isn't what you was going to hear, eh?

Comment: ya - exactly what I was thinking, just didn't know if there was another way that could easily be handled in magento.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a group email is the easy way.

Otherwise, you'd have to:

1. Create a new JS validation rule (via `Validation.add()` in `prototype/validation.js`)
2. Configure the field to use the new rule (`recipient_email` in `Mage/Contacts/etc/system.xml`)
3. Update the way the value is handled once validated (`postAction()` in `Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php`)

Here you can find code to use in the controller action: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/74568/

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to System > Configuration > Contacts and add your Email-id’s in comma delimit in “Send Emails To” field (eg: test@gmail.com,user1@gmail.com.user2@gmail.com)

Edit file **code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php** or make a module depending upon your requirement.

In **postAction** you should find a few lines of code that look like this:

```
$mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
 ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
 ->sendTransactional(
 Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
 Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
 Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
 null,
 array('data' => $postObject)
 );

if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
 throw new Exception();
 }
```

Change it to below:

```
$recipients = explode(",",Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT));
 foreach($recipients as $recipient){
 $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
 ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
 ->sendTransactional(
 Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
 Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
 $recipient,
 null,
 array('data' => $postObject)
 );

 if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
 throw new Exception();
 }
 }
```

Comment: The Javascript validation won't even allow you to get to this point and I would steer clear of recommending anyone to modify core code, encourage them to create a module so they don't break their upgrade path.

Comment: @veilig If you want multiple recipients then obviously you're going to create a new module (needless to say). Also we can override JS validation using class="validate-emails" to allow multiple email id's.